# Does Tor need more Relay node or Exit nodes?

Tags: tor, relay, exit

If I have free bandwidth, am I better off sharing as a relay node or exit node?

Trying to help the Tor network

Comment: I wouldn't suggest being an exit node, especially if you are in the US.  While some of the traffic is legit on there, it is often used to obscure illegal stuff that can get you in some fairly serious trouble.  The exit node owner is liable for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tor need more Relay Nodes, you also can modify exit policy to not open Websites and SSL.

There is the guide how to configure tor as relay via user interface Vidalia:

https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-relay

Answer (score 0):

From their site, they appear to be specifically interested in adding relay nodes.

https://www.torproject.org/getinvolved/volunteer.html.en

there are probably people you can contact via the volunteer page to ask any further questions you may have.